# Selenium don't read all the content of a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm newbie with selenium. I have defined a batch process where I process several pages. These pages are all equals but with different data. Therefore, I process all these pages with the same code. When I start the process this works fine, but, from time to time, I always get the same error in the same point. I have found that when I try to get the data from the web page, there are two tables that I can not get their code when the process doesn't work fine. And I don't understand anything because if I restart the process in the same page that has failed previously then it works fine!!! So, it seems that selenium not always load the content of the web page correctly.

I use python 3 and selenium with these code:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"
#b = WebDriver(executable_path="./chromedriver")
b = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path="./chromedriver")
b.set_window_size(300, 300)
b.get(url)
html = b.page_source
self.setSoup(bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser'))
b.close()
```

How can I avoid to get always this error which is produced from time to time?

**Edit I:**

I have checked that when the process works fine this sentence returns me two tables:

```
tables = self.get_soup().findAll("table", class_="competitor-table comparative responsive")
```

But, when the process works wrong, this code returns me 0 tables. How I said before, If I process again the web page that previously has gave me the error, then works fine, therefore, it returns me two tables instead of zero.

For this reason, I supose that selenium is not returns me always the code of the page, because for the same page when it works wrong returns me zero tables and when it works fine returns me two tables.

**Edit II:**

For example, right now I've got an error in this page:

```
http://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/18-19/game/1912/Olympiacos-Perfumerias-Avenida#|tab=boxscore
```

The tables that I try to retrieve and I don't get them are these:

[image]

How you can see, there is two tables with this CSS class. I don't post the content of the tables because are so big.

This is the code where I try to get the content of the tables:

```
def set_boxscore(self):
    tables = self.get_soup().findAll("table", class_="competitor-table comparative responsive")
    local = False
    print("Total tablas: {}".format(len(tables)))
    for t in tables:
        local = not local
        if local:
            self.home_team.set_stats(t.tfoot.find("tr", class_="team-totals"))
        else:
            self.away_team.set_stats(t.tfoot.find("tr", class_="team-totals"))
        rows = t.tbody.findAll("tr")
        for row in rows:
            time = row.find("td", class_="min").string
            if time.find(MESSAGES.MESSAGE_PLAYER_NOT_PLAY) == -1:
                if local:
                    player = PlayerEuropa(row)
                    self.home_players.append(player)
                else:
                    player = PlayerEuropa(row)
                    self.away_players.append(player)
```

In this code I write the total tables that I can find in them and how you can see, right now, I've got zero tables:

[image]

And, now, If I restart the process, then, it will work correctly for me.

**Edit III:**

One example more, about the process that I have defined. These url's has been processed correctly.

```
http://www.fiba.basketball/eurocupwomen/18-19/game/2510/VBW-CEKK-Ceglèd-Rutronik-Stars-Keltern#|tab=boxscore
http://www.fiba.basketball/eurocupwomen/18-19/game/2510/Elfic-Fribourg-Tarbes-GB#|tab=boxscore
http://www.fiba.basketball/eurocupwomen/18-19/game/2510/Basket-Landes-BBC-Sint-Katelijne-Waver#|tab=boxscore
```

But when I have tried to process this other url, then, I've got the error explained previously:

http://www.fiba.basketball/eurocupwomen/18-19/game/0111/Gorzow-Sparta-k-M-R--Vidnoje#|tab=boxscore

To render the web page I use selenium and I always do it at the beginning of the process. I get the content of the web page with this code:

```
def __init__(self, url):
    """Constructor"""
    caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
    caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"
    #b = WebDriver(executable_path="./chromedriver")
    b = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path="./chromedriver")
    b.set_window_size(300, 300)
    b.get(url)
    html = b.page_source
    self.setSoup(bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser'))
    b.close()
```

After this code is when I start to retrieve the information of the web page. For some reason, sometimes, the web page is not rendered completely because when I try to get some information, this is not found it and get the error explained previously.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why do you think that this is *"error"*? Selenium *"reads"* content available for that exact moment. If you got *incomplete* content that means you didn't [wait enough](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Comment: I have updated my original post @MateMrše

Comment: Hi, @Andersson I have updated my original post.

Comment: I guess your *"If I process again"* means that you're just getting cached HTML-source which contain required tables... Share more details like URLs or tables HTML, data you want to get, how you want to handle that data, etc... as for now your issue is too broad

Comment: I have updated my original post again @Andersson

Comment: Those tables are absent in page source, so you need to wait until JavaScript executed

Comment: How can I do that? Why sometimes I've got the tables and other times no with the same code?

Comment: Some tables might be static, the other are dynamic. You cannot use the same approach to get every table you want

Comment: Ok. But I don't understand why I can retrieve the content of these tables correctly sometimes and other times no with the same development.

Comment: You mean same script for same tables? I guess it depends on script execution time and page rendering time

Comment: Yes same script for same tables.